# I have a .NET C# Windows Form app erroring on Form1.Designer.cs

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, compiler-errors

I have a problem with a .NET C# Windows Form application in which I cannot get the form to show in debug mode or release mode. It used to, so something must have changed. I don't know what but when I want to test it and see the form appear like it used to it doesn't. It's a form with a 3 tabbed control on it each doing different things.

When I rebuild the debug version and hit play nothing happens, no form is shown. No errors are shown in the build window when I build it either.
So I start the debug nothing happens so I wait, it takes ages, and then I hit the pause button and it pauses on a random line e.g

```cs
this.lblTesting.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(45, 13);
```

with this error.

```
$exception error CS0103: The name '$exception' does not exist in the current context.
```

If I hit Continue then still no form shows and when I hit pause it just stops on this line.

```
this.tabControl.ResumeLayout(false);
```

With the error {"Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown."}

So I don't know how to rebuild the Form1.Designer.cs page so that it's all correct.

These were the errors I was getting after the final error.

```
Hunter.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Hunter.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Reid\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Hunter\Hunter\bin\Debug\Hunter.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Hunter.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Hunter.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Hunter.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Hunter.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Hunter.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Hunter.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Hunter.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Hunter.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Hunter.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Hunter.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Hunter.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Hunter.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

The program '[22072] Hunter.exe' has exited with code -2147023895 (0x800703e9).
```

So I read some articles from here and other places that said to go to the form, add in something new or change something and then save the form and rebuild it and then the designer class for the form with problems should be rebuilt however that didn't seem to fix my problem.

I try adding in a new label next to another one on the Form1.cs [Design], and changed the code in Form1.cs to output something in it rather than change the whole value of the original label as it was doing.

This let me build it with no errors occurring.

However on Debug Play it did the same thing as before.

I then accidentally added a new form. I didn't want this form so I tried in the solution to right click expecting a "delete" or "remove form" option but none appeared. I went into the File Browser and just deleted anything that started with Form2. Then I read that I should open up the Hunter.csproj in notepad and remove references to that form which I did.

Now when I try to go to Form1.cs [Design] I get the error page that says:

```
The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed. 

Instances of this error (1)  
 
1.   Hide Call Stack 
 
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.EnsureDocument(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)
```

I have tried using the "Clean Solution" option, "Run code analysis on solution", and "Rebuild" but I cannot get that form to show up. So I have no scooby doo what to do.

The link on the page takes me to > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/design-time-errors-in-the-windows-forms-designer?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(WhyDTELPage);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.8)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

which is no good as there is no "ignore and continue" button shown or any yellow bar to go to the error. However if I search for the error at the top there is a section that says

> The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed.
>
> This error occurs when Visual Studio cannot find a base class that satisfies designer requirements. Forms and controls must derive from a base class that supports designers. If you're deriving from an inherited form or control, make sure the project has been built.

I just don't know why there is not "Fix" button, that will re-apply all the properties you have set on the actual Form Design page to the Form Designer Class. Or if you just saved the form page it rebuilds the class. There must be away to rebuild the class behind the form correctly from the properties and toolbox objects you created the form with? That would be a very good idea for Microsoft to add in to the IDE :), it analyses the code, any bugs and error messages and does its best to fix the project automatically.

So I have no idea what to do. How can I rebuild the whole Form1.Designer.cs class that I don't remember touching in the first place. How to get my form back, how to rebuild it so the form designer class is correct and run debug to actually see a form.

This is the whole class of the Form1.Designer.cs class -as requested by a comment to show

```
namespace Hunter
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.tabControl = new System.Windows.Forms.TabControl();
        this.tabPage1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
        this.lblLocalHostNameValue = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.listBoxPing = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
        this.lstLocalIP = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
        this.lblLocalHostName = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lblUserIPDetails = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lblOnlineStatus = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label6 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.tabPage2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
        this.lblStatus = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lblCountry = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.cmdCancel = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.cmdClear = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.lblPing = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.ProgressBar = new System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar();
        this.lblHostName = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lblTesting = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lblValidIP = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.txtIPAddress = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.cmdStartScan = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.PortScanResults = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
        this.tabPage3 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
        this.lblProxyListStatus = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.ProxyProgressBar = new System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar();
        this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.button3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.label10 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lstProxies = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
        this.tabControl.SuspendLayout();
        this.tabPage1.SuspendLayout();
        this.tabPage2.SuspendLayout();
        this.tabPage3.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // tabControl
        // 
        this.tabControl.Controls.Add(this.tabPage1);
        this.tabControl.Controls.Add(this.tabPage2);
        this.tabControl.Controls.Add(this.tabPage3);
        this.tabControl.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top;
        this.tabControl.HotTrack = true;
        this.tabControl.ItemSize = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 18);
        this.tabControl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.tabControl.Name = "tabControl";
        this.tabControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
        this.tabControl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(791, 401);
        this.tabControl.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // tabPage1
        // 
        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.lblLocalHostNameValue);
        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.listBoxPing);
        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.lstLocalIP);
        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.lblLocalHostName);
        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.label3);
        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.lblUserIPDetails);
        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.lblOnlineStatus);
        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.label6);
        this.tabPage1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
        this.tabPage1.Name = "tabPage1";
        this.tabPage1.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
        this.tabPage1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(783, 375);
        this.tabPage1.TabIndex = 3;
        this.tabPage1.Text = "Home";
        this.tabPage1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.tabPage1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.tabPage1_Click);
        // 
        // lblLocalHostNameValue
        // 
        this.lblLocalHostNameValue.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblLocalHostNameValue.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(105, 37);
        this.lblLocalHostNameValue.Name = "lblLocalHostNameValue";
        this.lblLocalHostNameValue.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(22, 13);
        this.lblLocalHostNameValue.TabIndex = 31;
        this.lblLocalHostNameValue.Text = "NA";
        // 
        // listBoxPing
        // 
        this.listBoxPing.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.listBoxPing.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(403, 17);
        this.listBoxPing.Name = "listBoxPing";
        this.listBoxPing.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(354, 82);
        this.listBoxPing.TabIndex = 30;
        this.listBoxPing.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.listBoxPing_SelectedIndexChanged);
        // 
        // lstLocalIP
        // 
        this.lstLocalIP.HideSelection = false;
        this.lstLocalIP.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 125);
        this.lstLocalIP.Name = "lstLocalIP";
        this.lstLocalIP.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(760, 182);
        this.lstLocalIP.TabIndex = 12;
        this.lstLocalIP.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
        this.lstLocalIP.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
        // 
        // lblLocalHostName
        // 
        this.lblLocalHostName.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblLocalHostName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(29, 37);
        this.lblLocalHostName.Name = "lblLocalHostName";
        this.lblLocalHostName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(60, 13);
        this.lblLocalHostName.TabIndex = 29;
        this.lblLocalHostName.Text = "Host Name";
        // 
        // label3
        // 
        this.label3.AutoSize = true;
        this.label3.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(29, 15);
        this.label3.Name = "label3";
        this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(349, 13);
        this.label3.TabIndex = 27;
        this.label3.Text = "Details about the local computer the program is running from";
        // 
        // lblUserIPDetails
        // 
        this.lblUserIPDetails.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblUserIPDetails.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(29, 90);
        this.lblUserIPDetails.Name = "lblUserIPDetails";
        this.lblUserIPDetails.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(111, 13);
        this.lblUserIPDetails.TabIndex = 26;
        this.lblUserIPDetails.Text = "Local Machine IP Info";
        // 
        // lblOnlineStatus
        // 
        this.lblOnlineStatus.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblOnlineStatus.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.lblOnlineStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkBlue;
        this.lblOnlineStatus.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(102, 65);
        this.lblOnlineStatus.Name = "lblOnlineStatus";
        this.lblOnlineStatus.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(44, 13);
        this.lblOnlineStatus.TabIndex = 25;
        this.lblOnlineStatus.Text = "Offline";
        // 
        // label6
        // 
        this.label6.AutoSize = true;
        this.label6.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label6.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(29, 65);
        this.label6.Name = "label6";
        this.label6.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(76, 13);
        this.label6.TabIndex = 24;
        this.label6.Text = "Online Status: ";
        // 
        // tabPage2
        // 
        this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.lblStatus);
        this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.lblCountry);
        this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.cmdCancel);
        this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.cmdClear);
        this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.lblPing);
        this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.ProgressBar);
        this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.lblHostName);
        this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.lblTesting);
        this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.lblValidIP);
        this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.label2);
        this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.txtIPAddress);
        this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.cmdStartScan);
        this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.PortScanResults);
        this.tabPage2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
        this.tabPage2.Name = "tabPage2";
        this.tabPage2.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
        this.tabPage2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(783, 375);
        this.tabPage2.TabIndex = 1;
        this.tabPage2.Text = "Port Scan";
        this.tabPage2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // lblStatus
        // 
        this.lblStatus.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblStatus.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.lblStatus.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(510, 17);
        this.lblStatus.Name = "lblStatus";
        this.lblStatus.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(61, 13);
        this.lblStatus.TabIndex = 26;
        this.lblStatus.Text = "WAITING";
        // 
        // lblCountry
        // 
        this.lblCountry.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblCountry.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.lblCountry.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(507, 94);
        this.lblCountry.Name = "lblCountry";
        this.lblCountry.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(95, 17);
        this.lblCountry.TabIndex = 25;
        this.lblCountry.Text = "Country: NA";
        this.lblCountry.Visible = false;
        // 
        // cmdCancel
        // 
        this.cmdCancel.Enabled = false;
        this.cmdCancel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(530, 319);
        this.cmdCancel.Name = "cmdCancel";
        this.cmdCancel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(112, 23);
        this.cmdCancel.TabIndex = 24;
        this.cmdCancel.Text = "Cancel";
        this.cmdCancel.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.cmdCancel.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.cmdCancel_Click);
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(180, -40);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(69, 20);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 23;
        this.label1.Text = "Waiting";
        // 
        // cmdClear
        // 
        this.cmdClear.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(412, 319);
        this.cmdClear.Name = "cmdClear";
        this.cmdClear.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(112, 23);
        this.cmdClear.TabIndex = 22;
        this.cmdClear.Text = "Clear";
        this.cmdClear.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.cmdClear.Click += new 
        System.EventHandler(this.cmdClear_Click);
        // lblHostName
        // 
        this.lblHostName.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblHostName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(507, 39);
        this.lblHostName.Name = "lblHostName";
        this.lblHostName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(66, 13);
        this.lblHostName.TabIndex = 19;
        this.lblHostName.Text = "Host Name: ";
        this.lblHostName.Visible = false;
        // 
        // lblTesting
        // 
        this.lblTesting.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblTesting.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(36, 168);
        this.lblTesting.Name = "lblTesting";
        this.lblTesting.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(45, 13);
        this.lblTesting.TabIndex = 18;
        this.lblTesting.Text = "Testing:";
        this.lblTesting.Visible = false;
        // 
        // lblValidIP
        // 
        this.lblValidIP.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblValidIP.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        this.lblValidIP.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(122, 243);
        this.lblValidIP.Name = "lblValidIP";
        this.lblValidIP.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 13);
        this.lblValidIP.TabIndex = 17;
        this.lblValidIP.Text = "Valid";
        this.lblValidIP.Visible = false;
        // 
        // label2
        // 
        this.label2.AutoSize = true;
        this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(36, 243);
        this.label2.Name = "label2";
        this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(58, 13);
        this.label2.TabIndex = 16;
        this.label2.Text = "IP Address";
        // 
        // txtIPAddress
        // 
        this.txtIPAddress.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(36, 256);
        this.txtIPAddress.Name = "txtIPAddress";
        this.txtIPAddress.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(192, 20);
        this.txtIPAddress.TabIndex = 15;
        this.txtIPAddress.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.txtIPAddress_TextChanged);
        // 
        // cmdStartScan
        // 
        this.cmdStartScan.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(648, 319);
        this.cmdStartScan.Name = "cmdStartScan";
        this.cmdStartScan.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(112, 23);
        this.cmdStartScan.TabIndex = 14;
        this.cmdStartScan.Text = "Start Scan";
        this.cmdStartScan.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.cmdStartScan.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.cmdStartScan_Click);
        // 
        // PortScanResults
        // 
        this.PortScanResults.HideSelection = false;
        this.PortScanResults.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(36, 14);
        this.PortScanResults.Name = "PortScanResults";
        this.PortScanResults.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(430, 138);
        this.PortScanResults.TabIndex = 13;
        this.PortScanResults.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
        this.PortScanResults.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
        // 
        // tabPage3
        // 
        this.tabPage3.Controls.Add(this.lblProxyListStatus);
        this.tabPage3.Controls.Add(this.ProxyProgressBar);
        this.tabPage3.Controls.Add(this.button2);
        this.tabPage3.Controls.Add(this.button3);
        this.tabPage3.Controls.Add(this.label10);
        this.tabPage3.Controls.Add(this.lstProxies);
        this.tabPage3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
        this.tabPage3.Name = "tabPage3";
        this.tabPage3.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
        this.tabPage3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(783, 375);
        this.tabPage3.TabIndex = 2;
        this.tabPage3.Text = "Proxies";
        this.tabPage3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // lblProxyListStatus
        // 
        this.lblProxyListStatus.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblProxyListStatus.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(18, 287);
        this.lblProxyListStatus.Name = "lblProxyListStatus";
        this.lblProxyListStatus.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(81, 13);
        this.lblProxyListStatus.TabIndex = 19;
        this.lblProxyListStatus.Text = "Checking Proxy";
        // 
        // ProxyProgressBar
        // 
        this.ProxyProgressBar.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 241);
        this.ProxyProgressBar.Name = "ProxyProgressBar";
        this.ProxyProgressBar.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(760, 23);
        this.ProxyProgressBar.TabIndex = 18;
        // 
        // button2
        // 
        this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(512, 314);
        this.button2.Name = "button2";
        this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(112, 23);
        this.button2.TabIndex = 17;
        this.button2.Text = "Find Proxies";
        this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
        // 
        // button3
        // 
        this.button3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(647, 314);
        this.button3.Name = "button3";
        this.button3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(112, 23);
        this.button3.TabIndex = 16;
        this.button3.Text = "Check Proxies";
        this.button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button3_Click);
        // 
        // label10
        // 
        this.label10.AutoSize = true;
        this.label10.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label10.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 17);
        this.label10.Name = "label10";
        this.label10.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(48, 13);
        this.label10.TabIndex = 13;
        this.label10.Text = "Proxies";
        // 
        // lstProxies
        // 
        this.lstProxies.HideSelection = false;
        this.lstProxies.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 41);
        this.lstProxies.Name = "lstProxies";
        this.lstProxies.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(760, 182);
        this.lstProxies.TabIndex = 12;
        this.lstProxies.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
        this.lstProxies.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(791, 413);
        this.Controls.Add(this.tabControl);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Proxy Hunter";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        this.tabControl.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.tabPage1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.tabPage1.PerformLayout();
        this.tabPage2.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.tabPage2.PerformLayout();
        this.tabPage3.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.tabPage3.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.TabControl tabControl;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPage2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPage3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar ProxyProgressBar;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label10;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ListView lstProxies;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblCountry;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button cmdCancel;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button cmdClear;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblPing;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar ProgressBar;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblHostName;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblTesting;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblValidIP;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtIPAddress;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button cmdStartScan;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ListView PortScanResults;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblStatus;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPage1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblUserIPDetails;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblOnlineStatus;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label6;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblLocalHostName;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblProxyListStatus;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ListView lstLocalIP;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBoxPing;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblLocalHostNameValue;
}
}
```

Comment: Somehow by a circular restart of VS 2017 that happened about 3 times the error page has gone away instead of my form design page however when I hit the play button to debug run, it still stops on the this.tabControl.ResumeLayout(false); line if I wait long enough for it to just stop and error without hitting pause - which just stops at any line and shows that exception is not defined error. So how do I rebuild the Form1.Designer.cs class so that it is rebuilt properly using my drag n drop tools n tabs, labels etc. As I have no idea why it is erroring where it is and not showing the form.

Comment: I found an old version VS 2010 of the project and in the same file it only has two tabs, one with anything on. The code from old file has no this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load); in the method, but has this.tabControl.ResumeLayout(false);
this.tabPage3.ResumeLayout(false);
this.tabPage3.PerformLayout();
this.ResumeLayout(false); and it works and shows the form. I've tried copying it in but that makes no difference, If I leave an empty partial class, then the design mode form is empty so rebuilding makes nothing. I don;t know how to rebuild this designer class so it works

Comment: You seem to have some recursion bug in your form startup code. Can you show the top entries of the stack when it crashes?

Comment: It might also help to post your Form1.Designer.cs and Form1.cs code.

Comment: How do I post all that code in a comment box or is there some other way as the code is long for the designer.cs class, the stack error message is the one I posted in the main thread e.g when the debugger stops finally on that Resume.Layout(false) line. That is what is shown in the error/build part that I can see, that's all I get and if I hit pause before it stops (after 2+ mins), it will just error on any line with $exception is not defined - and the last error is a buffer overflow. But the stack message is all in that 1st box  under "These were the errors I was getting after the final error"

Comment: Sorry I never realised there was an edit box, but the code was too long to save so I have removed some code that never ended the debug with an error which was to do with lblPing. So if you see lblPing or txtPing etc referenced but cannot see the declarations of size, position, text, name etc thats because I had to remove it so I could save the post in EDIT mode for you to see.

Comment: I cannot post my Form1.cs code in that same post (Editing it), as it was already too long just adding in the Form1.designer.cs class (which I had to remove sections from anyway - to do with Ping) so if you know how I can post another long class into that edit box which is limited by chars then please let me know and I will - and it does sound circular but always finishes (if I don't hit pause which just causes an $exception is not defined) on any line it paused on -> on this line this.tabControl.ResumeLayout(false); which is the last line in InitializeComponent method.

Comment: The project was just an old 2010 project I had started (a Port Scanner), that I changed into a 3 tabbed layout, one which shows your PC host, outside IP (v4 & v6), and internal IPs, Ping & Tracert to prove outside contact, a page that lists a load of proxies it tests and the orig port scanner to test multi threading. I just want to know how to rebuild the class that lies behind a form, there must be a way that VS can take all your properties from the form you designed and rebuild that class somehow. if not there should be. A rebuild designer class button or something like that would be great

Comment: I tried putting a Try/Catch around the line that errrored to see if I could get more info but it still errors saying unhandled exception despite being within a StackOverflow Exception Catch.

try
{
 this.tabControl.ResumeLayout(false); PerformLayout statements
}
catch (System.StackOverflowException ex)
{
 throw new System.Exception("Error: " + ex.Message.ToString() + "; Stack: " + ex.StackTrace.ToString());
}

Comment: but it still errors on that line within the try/catch with StackOverFlow Exception. If I expand the exception dialog, I get under Exception->Data->Keys->Results View. Next to Results View it says 
"Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable" Underneath that is a red cross and next to it "The runtime refused to evaluate the expression at this time." I don't know if this is something important like the class is trying to add a listview item on the page but can't evaluate the items sized/named inside it as that is done at runtime?

Comment: This works for on VS Enterprise 2019 Version 16.9.1 on .NET Framework 4.7.1 and .NET 5. The only thing I changed was remove the event handlers so I can make it compile. Can you post the .cs file too? Is it possible that you have code in the default constructor that breaks your designer? Can you move your form a on clean project and reproduce it? Try removing all code form the default constructor

Comment: I have the same behavior as George. It works when I removed the handlers. Try to comment all handlers (+= new System.EventHandler)

Comment: First, how can I post this code, I am already Over the limit StackOverflow allows to post in their box. I will try removing the event handlers. But didn't know u can just copy n paste a whole form (3 tabbed pages), with loads of items from one project to another. I tried to see how I could right click n "copy" to do that the other day but it wouldn't let me. Im using VS 2017

Comment: When you say code in the default constructor do u mean in Form1.cs, as I only have one method call to start off the form running which had been working all the time. No code in the Designer. In Form1.cs I have public Form1()
{            
 InitializeComponent();

 Form1 frm = new Form1();

 frm.Show();

 //DoFormChecks(); // my code to start the form running automatically should I add a button and put it behind that? Its commented out and still doesnt work though.
}

Comment: By the way it compiles it just doesn't run, when I hit debug play, it just hangs for ages then errors on that last line in the Form1.Designer.cs class after a few minutes,

Comment: I tried commenting out all the Event handlers like  > //this.button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button3_Click); > But it compiled still, didn't remakes the file or put the Events back in and then errored again on this.tabPage1.ResumeLayout(false); > As I said when I hit build it builds with NO errors and lets me hit the Debug play button but then hangs for a few mins before erroring on that line with this error > Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.> No line no etc

Comment: I added a button to the main tab (tab1), and put DoFormChecks() from the Form1.cs constructor into it. It added the code for the button into the Designer, compiled but still errored after a few mins on the line this.tabControl.ResumeLayout(false); -- so something else must be going on. It will take me too long to recreate the whole 3 tabbed form in another project, and I don't know or see a way to copy the whole Form (Design) from one project into another without recreating every single element in the new project which will take ages.

Answer (score 0):

Well I've fixed it, not sure when or why it went wrong. Wish I could add more code into these boxes though to show people.

In the form1.cs default constructor was

```
public Form1()
{            
    InitializeComponent();

    Form1 frm = new Form1();

    frm.Show();

    this.DoFormChecks(); // my code to start the form and all 3 tabs init, creating 1 instance of a class I use and define columns for listviews. This WAS WORKING....
 }
```

So I changed this to

```
public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();            
}
```

Put a button on the 1st tab that wasn't originally there or needed and put the code behind that button e.g

```
private void cmdTab1Run_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Form1 frm = new Form1();           

    this.DoTab1Checks();        // instead of this.DoFormChecks() so it only does anything related to that tab    
}
```

So I set my class up for each tab now, rather than once for the whole form as I used to.

It complies as it always did but now shows automatically without the frm.Show(); command used anywhere which was in the constructor.

And on every tab the start button does the same thing, creates a new Form1(), then init my class, then runs the code needed JUST for that tab.

It was working until I fell asleep at the desk one night woke up and it wasn't. Had no clue to what went wrong or anyway to fix it.

I guess the code behind this.DoFormChecks(); was trying to set column widths and initialise objects that couldn't be used on the 2nd/3rd tab or something.

I really have no idea but I guess it was down to the 3 tabbed control I was using that stopped it.

So it wasn't a case of rebuilding the Form1.Designer.cs as I thought and no error messages helped me work it out but it was just trial and error guess work that made it work.

Now I have 3 classes initialised at the same time if you got to all 3 tabs and hit the button rather than just one that used to do it all.

Answer (score 0):

1. About the designer crashing
   Usually there is something working
   in your designer.cs code or something breaks it because of logic in
   your default (parameterless constructor).
2. Now, about your case
   A) Of course it crashes, I'm surprize this ever worked.
   I guess you didn't paste your actual code.
   You can't use a method/constructor inside the method/constructor like that, that's infinite recursion :)
   B) Why would you ever want to do this?
   You already have a form that will be shown.
   C)Whatever logic you want to perform, move it to the Load event

   ```
   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.Load += Form1_Load;
   }

   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       this.DoFormChecks();
   }
   ```

3.Don't create Forms on every button click, it doesn't make sense and it wont' really help.
Do you have any static/global data that is initialized/verified in you constructor?Try to avoid this.
In any case, check your business logic again, that's where the problem is.

Comment: Yes I had a method that ran automatically when I opened the form. It was working fine and then I woke up and it didn;t work. The Form1.Designer.cs always compiled it was just when I hit play it didn't do anything for a few mins before crashing with said bug. I wanted to post the code but the box only allows 3000 chars so I couldn't edit it and add it in as well as the designer code - what do ppl normally do when they want to show code too long for the box to ask the question. I will try moving some stuff about as you said to see if it works still

Comment: @MonkeyMagix never had this issue before,you can push the code to a GitHub repo and share the link

Comment: I changed the code as you said but in the private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    this.DoFormChecks;
}
method I now get the error "Only assignment, call increment, decrement, await and new object expressions can be used as a statement" - and u say it's recursive, but that answer I posted of creating a form in each tab did actually solve the problem. Not sure why I cannot call my DoFormChecks() from inside the Form1_Load() method though.

Comment: I just put the code you had put in Form1_Load() to call this.DoFormChecks() into the Form1_Load() e.g private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyHunter = new Hunter();
    MyHunter.RunCode();
} and now it works. Not sure why a call to DoFormChecks with the same code in it would not let me compile it with the above error though. Now its working. No Form creation in each button click and the global obj init in the Form1_Load() now....

Comment: @MonkeyMagix So, is you problem solved? These look like bugs somewhere in your logic, no one will be able to help without the full picture. If you need additional help, reproduce this on a small, clean project and upload it to GitHub so others can access it

Comment: The problem is solved. I did post an answer but it's been hidden. I don't know why from Form1_Load() I couldn't call DoFormChecks() like you suggested but putting the two lines of code from that method that init the global Hunter class into Form1_Load() works. Not sure why that error about "Only assignment, call increment, decrement, await and new object expressions can be used as a statement" came up when putting DoFormChecks() into Form1_Load() though?? Would like to know as all I did was move the 2 lines of code from that method into Form1_Load() and it compiled and works. Odd.

Comment: Its a muck about project, e.g just for me learning .NET C# forms, network, threading, geoip, pings etc. The 2 lines in the init just create a global memory stream of geoip data that can be used by all 3 tabs all doing different things. Therefore I have no idea why the DoFormChecks(); wouldn't work but the 2 lines to init the Class n load the geoip data into memory would in Form1_Load(). It was just 1 method calling another. This way is neater anyway as the DoFormChecks was not really needed in 1st place. But thanks for your help.

Comment: You had: `this.DoFormChecks;` without parentheses after. That's why you got that error.

Comment: explains that compile error then but the method wasn't really needed when I could just add the Hunter() class init into the Page_Load() event anyway.

Comment: although I cannot remember doing that as I just copied the code, I didn't rewrite it just copied n pasted it so I don't know why I would have removed the brackets unless sleep coding or something - which isn't unusual I've done a ton of things in my sleep, slept walked down a flight of stairs broke my arm n dislocated it at same time and also sleep betting which got me thrown of Bet365 as I was winning al the time on sports I knew nothing about like Mens Lacrosse ( I dont even know what that is or which teams r good ) - and Female Tennis - I have no idea about those sports but won £ got booted

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guessing, since you cannot provide all information.
However:
Do not derive from Form Class ^^

Don't Example: class YourClass : Form -> This will actually build and also work for some time but it is wrong in most cases.

Address your Form with Form.YourInternalVariable.* Whatever you want from her.